# Is there such a thing as DNS proxy?

Tags: dns, proxy, http

My vintage PCs are on a separate LAN with no Internet connection. I wish to use Netscape to connect to some selected internet sites, so I have set up CCProxy on a Win11 box. This Win11 box is connected to the vintage LAN and the regular home router as well.

I was hoping to be able to access some HTTP sites via this proxy, but apparently something is missing.

Maybe what's missing is DNS -- how could a PC (that is connected to this separate LAN only) find out IP addresses?

CCProxy has a checkbox for DNS, but there is no 'DNS proxy' option in Netscape.

Update: the symptom is that Netscape is unable to connect. Also, CCProxy does not show any activity in the monitoring.

Update: I specifically want plain HTTP currently.

Comment: Not an answer: check out https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/browse-the-web-like-its-the-90s-with-this-free-service/ & https://oldweb.today

Comment: Can you at least describe the symptoms of a failed connection from any of the PCs?

Comment: Admittedly I've not done it in a while but DNS worked fine the last time I used a pre-historic OS, it was most sites going HTTPs, and the web standards that were the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is a bit different – most web sites these days use (and automatically redirect to) HTTPS, not just plain HTTP; and it doesn't look like CCProxy can intercept that.

When HTTPS is being proxied, the browser doesn't just send the whole URL and have the proxy retrieve it – it has the proxy establish a *direct tunnel* to the HTTPS server, so that the browser itself remains the TLS endpoint. But nowadays sites use TLS parameters completely incompatible with even the most recent Netscape, so you'll need a proxy that *does* deliberately intercept the TLS connection and act as a fake SSL server (with a fake certificate of course).

For old *Windows* systems, at least, there is Retrozilla 2.2 with TLSv1.2 and AES-GCM support. (It still needs some about:config changes to activate AES-GCM.)

> Maybe what's missing is DNS -- how could a PC (that is connected to this separate LAN only) find out IP addresses?

It shouldn't need to find out IP addresses at all. Requests that go through an HTTP proxy always specify the original URL – the client does not attempt to resolve the hostname if it's using a proxy; it lets the proxy do it.

So if you're using an HTTP proxy, the only hostname that Netscape needs to be able to resolve is that of the proxy itself.

> Is there such a thing as DNS proxy?

Yes, and you're already using one every day – the DNS service in your home router is, literally, a caching DNS proxy that just forwards requests to another upstream resolver.

(Whereas that upstream DNS server has a bit more logic to be called a "proxy" – it's a whole "resolver" – but...since it still doesn't *host* any DNS data, its only job is to gather data from other (authoritative) DNS servers, you could still consider it kind of a "proxy".)

So if you want to host your own, just use any common "DNS resolver" software such as Unbound, pdnsd, dnsmasq, or even BIND9. (Some of these can either proxy to a single upstream server or directly gather data on their own, while others are proxy-only.)

> CCProxy has a checkbox for DNS, but there is no 'DNS proxy' option in Netscape.

It's not configured in Netscape because you already configure it globally (OS-wide) in the TCP/IP settings, through the "DNS server" field (or through /etc/resolv.conf on Unix systems).

Comment: thank you for your explanation. The problem must be somewhere in the local network then. I can ping each computer from the other and firewall is disabled so what can be wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest installing a packet capture tool to see what's happening. (Wireshark for modern systems, previously known as Ethereal for older Linux or Win98, tcpdump for Linux, snoop on Sun...)